# ASP.Net Cart - Duplicate Session IDs

Tags: asp.net, .net, e-commerce

Can anyone tell me what is happenning here?  I am getting duplicated session ID's across 2 seperate machines, 2 different browsers in a shopping cart website?

I've gone so far as generating a new session id with a 300 character random string, and still they get duplicated

This is the new code...  just take out the SyncLock stuff for the old code:

```
    Dim _key As String = String.Empty
    SyncLock _locker
        _key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        Session("Identifier") = Validations.GeneratePassword(150, 300)
        Session("SessionID") = _key
        Session("SiteID") = "F2630237-E355-4C8A-947E-BBAC97ECA550"
        Session("HomePage") = 13
    End SyncLock
```

yes I know Session("SessionID") is not the session ID, however, we used to use Session.SessionID for the "Identifier", and it was getting duplicated

Comment: You generated the session yourself? Can you post the code that generates the session?

Comment: You'll need to post some code so that we can see what your code is doing! How is the session ID being stored?

Comment: used to use the built in Session.SessionID, however, it was happenning with that

Comment: I just added in a SyncLock to see is this will get around it, I also turned off output caching in IIS for .aspx pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this.

if i set the session manager in web.config to be my class, and it worked

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="o7th.Projects.Core.SessionManager"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you generate your own `SessionID`?
ASP.NET and the browser do this out of the box and probably better that you or I.

I recommend you use this instead:

[HttpSessionState.SessionID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx)

Comment: we used to use the Session.SessionID as an identifier for the "cart".  But we started getting the duplicatations across machines, so we went with generating a random length, random alphanumeric string, and it still happens

Comment: I have searched around for this issue, and it seems by what I am seeing, is that I am not the only one...

Comment: I understand that, however, I figured there are pretty good odds that a random string that is randomly between 150 and 300 characters should do the trick ;)   Besides, nothing works.  New Guid does not work, sessionID does not work...  they all produce duplicates

Comment: @rick schott     there are many reports about generating a duplicate session id, if something is generated at random , there is a chance for duplication, no matter what technique is used (personnel opinion)

Answer (score 1):

I am rather doing a different approach

I created a table with identity, every time when needed a session id , an insertion is made and stored in session variable

I think random generators cannot be trusted